# Javascript, Make multiple text hidden text input visibile onchange

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ok, here is my new javascript code as it sits now:

```
var counter = <? echo $count-1 ?>;
var limit = 24;

function addInput(divName){
 if (counter >= limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

      var dropDown;

      var fromPHP=<? echo $s_to_json ?>;

      for (i=0; i<fromPHP.length; i++){
        yourValue = fromPHP[i];
        dropDown = dropDown + "<option value='" + yourValue + "'>" + yourValue + "</option>";
      }
      //document.write(dropDown);
      var containerType = "<?echo $matRow['container']?>";
      var viz;

      if (containerType == "Box/Bag"){
        viz = "visible";
      }else{
        viz = "hidden";
      }

      newdiv.innerHTML = "Weight " + (counter + 1) + ": <input type='text' name='myWeights[]' class='putty' maxlength='6' /> Material " + (counter + 1) + ": <input type='text' name='myMaterials[]' class='plato' maxlength='17' value='<? echo (isset($matRow['material']) ? $matRow['material'] : '')?>' /> Container " + (counter + 1) + ": <select onchange=\"switchMain(this.nextSibling.nextSibling.id);\" name='myContainers[]' id='myContainers[]'><option value='<? echo (isset($matRow['container']) ? $matRow['container'] : '') ?>' selected><? echo (isset($matRow['container']) ? $matRow['container'] : '') ?></option>' + dropDown + '" + dropDown + "</select><div id='boxhide[]' style='visibility:" + viz + ";display:inline;'> Quantity " + (counter + 1) + ": <input type='text' name='boxnum" + (counter + 1) +"' class='boxputty' maxlength='2' /></div>";
      document.getElementById(divName).lastChild.parentNode.appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
 }
}

function getStyle(divName){

var temp = document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility;

return temp;
}

function switchMain(divName){

//var e = document.getElementById("myContainers[]");
//var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

//console.debug(strUser);
//console.debug(divName);

if (strUser == "Box/Bag"){

    var current = getStyle(divName);

    //console.debug(current);

    document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility = "visible";
}else{
    document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
}

function removeInput(divName){

if (counter<=1){
    alert("You cannot remove any more weights from this job.");
}
else {
    var olddiv = document.getElementById(divName);
    var lastChild = olddiv.lastChild;
        if (lastChild && lastChild.parentNode && lastChild.parentNode.removeChild){
            lastChild.parentNode.removeChild(lastChild);
            counter--;
        }
}
}
```

And here is the portion of the script that calls upon it:

```
Weight <? echo $count ?>: <input type="text" class="putty" name="myWeights[]" maxlength="6" value="<? echo $read ?>" autofocus /> Material <? echo $count ?>: <input type="text" class="plato" name="myMaterials[]" maxlength="17" value="<? echo (isset($matRow["material"]) ? $matRow["material"] : "") ?>" />
        Container <? echo $count ?>: <select onchange="switchMain(this.nextSibling.nextSibling.id);" name="myContainers[]" id="myContainers[]">
            <option value="<? echo (isset($matRow["container"]) ? $matRow["container"] : "") ?>" selected><? echo (isset($matRow["container"]) ? $matRow["container"] : ""); ($matRow['container'] == 'Box/Bag' ? $vishid = 'visible' : $vishid = 'hidden') ?></option>
                <?

            <div id='boxhide[]' style="visibility:<? echo $vishid ?>;display:inline;">
            Quantity <? echo $count ?>: <input type="text" name="boxnum[]" class="boxputty" maxlength="2" />
            </div>


    <input type="button" alt='Add Weight' title='Add Weight' value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
    <input type="button" alt='Remove Weight' title='Remove Weight' value="-" onClick="removeInput('dynamicInput');">
```

I cut out all the bit that should be unnecessary.

As of right now when the user clicks to add a row it places it in the wrong spot but I am sure I can sort that out as I had to before. The larger issue is that any row added by clicking the '+' button gets an error when changing the dropdown menu that is checked by switchMain(). The error reads "TypeError: this.nextSibling.nextSibling is null."

Any advice would be great! Thanks!

Comment: hi. this code is almost unreadable (unfixable). My recommendation would be to not add the javascript code to your innerHTML object, but add the javascript functionality after you added the element to the dom. ex. document.getElementById(divName).onclick = function(){..};

Comment: If you could give me an example of code or a link as to the difference between what you are talking about vs innerHTML I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

So here are some obvious, though not necessarily easy to hear, suggestions for cleaning up your coding approach to make your life easier, and potentially make your questions more answerable in the future:

### Separate the php and js cleanly

Separate the php and javascript as much as possible.  If you must pass data from js to php, I suggest a much more disciplined approach that pre-initializes all php variables and then uses them in the javascript later:

```
var counter = <? js_escape($count-1); ?>;
var fromPHP=<? js_escape($s_to_json); ?>; // Null if not available
var jsVarFromPhp = <?php escape($necessary_var);?>;
var anotherVariable = <?php escape($another_var);?>;
var materialArray = <? echo json_encode($material_array);?>;

// then the js actually does stuff with javascript variables, ideally wrapped within a function, no php in the logic of your javascript.
```

### Isolate the javascript behavior

When you're dealing with a complex combination of languages like this, often it's good to isolate the php behavior from the javascript behavior.  http://jsfiddle.net is great for this, take the js behavior that you intend, and the html that you expect, and put it into a test case.  You'll have to turn your php variables into their values, but it will simplify the test case, so that's recommended to debug even for yourself.

### Get out of the habit of using echo directly in your html

You are echoing stuff directly in your html.  That will lead to XSS eventually.  Save yourself the trouble and work with a templating engine (a tiny one if it's only a tiny project).  Smarty is popular, and works.  If you feel you -must- work in native php for some reason, try to avoid php logic in your html and give yourself a wrapper function to make the php as clean as possible, like:

```
function h($dirty){
    echo htmlentities($dirty, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Used like so:

```
<input value='<?php h($input_value);?>'>
```

I still recommend the template engine approach, though.

Comment: I appreciate that. I do recognize I have been getting sloppy as I have been trying to get this script to work.

I will try to clean it up and resubmit the code. In the meanwhile, is there anything I can do to make sure the entire DOM is accessible? It was suggested to not use innerHTML but instead something more like,
 
    document.getElementById(divName).onclick = function(){..};

by superby. The only issue I didn't exactly follow him. I was hoping to be able to access a resource to learn the difference.

Comment: You don't have any kind of timing in place to ensure that the dom is ready by the time you perform operations upon it. https://github.com/ded/domready  Is a just-the-domready-function set of code that may be useful.  Then you can wrap javascript dom operations in that domready to ensure that you have the parts before you try to act on them.

Comment: As @superbly also hints at: any time you use onchange in innerhtml inside a javascript function, populated by php variables inside html... ...there is little way to debug such complexity, so you really want to use js functions instead of inline js, just to start.

Again, overall, I would just suggest you write out the html only, write out a `<script>` section of javascript only, and see if you can get the code working in that simplified environment, with sample data, before you even add the php back in.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed to hear. I will admit that I have gotten kinda lost in the JavaScript at this point.